# Laravel - Acessando caminho absoluto do diretório para download

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel

Criei um diretório dentro de /public chamado /uploads/pdf. Nesse diretório eu guardo arquivos PDF do qual preciso fazer o download. Criei uma requisição AJAX para isso que chama um controller da aplicação para isso, porém, via AJAX não funciona.

Se eu fizer a chamada normalmente funciona.

Vejam o código:

PDFClass.php //Classe que criei registrada globalmente

```
public static function createPDF($view){
    define('BUDGETS_DIR', public_path('uploads/pdf'));
    if (!is_dir(BUDGETS_DIR)){
        mkdir(BUDGETS_DIR, 0755, true);
    }

    $outputName = str_random(10);
    $pdfPath    = BUDGETS_DIR.'/'.$outputName.'.pdf';
    File::put($pdfPath, PDF::load($view, 'A4', 'portrait')->output());
}
```

Como podem ver, ele já tem a chamada para fazer o download do arquivo.

No controller eu faço a chamada desse método para criar o relatório e retornar.

ReservaController.php

```
   PDFClass::createPDF(HTMLRelatorio::confirmacaoReserva($fileServico,$motorista));
```

Que cria o arquivo PDF, salva ele no diretório especificado, mas... Não abre a janela de download pois a chamada é por AJAX...

A chamada na view:
reservado.blade.php

```
$(this).on('click','#imprimirConfirmacao',function(){
    var idFile = $('#id_file').val();
    var idServ = $('#id_servico').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/reserva/imprimir',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {idFile: idFile,idServ:idServ},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

Poderiam me ajudar com isso. Se alguém puder me passar um meio de baixar o arquivo via ajax ou uma forma de acessar o caminho absoluto para criar um link por Laravel eu agradeço, pois se eu fizer a chamada pelo navegador direto também retorna erro:

Vejam:

http://meusite.com/uploads/pdf/arquivo.pdf 
OU
http://meusite.com/public/uploads/pdf/arquivo.pdf

Retorna erro:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

Comment: Essa requisição é criada pois o relatório é criado na hora...

Answer (score 1):

você tem alguma rota chamada 'uploads' ? Se sim, esse erro pode ta acontecendo por isso, ele não acessa o arquivo na pasta uploads, mas tenta achar a action dessa rota...
Não há impedimentos no acesso aos arquivos na pasta /public, exceto se houver uma rota com mesmo nome que um dos arquivos ou pastas.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele.

Answer (score 0):

Quando isso acontece eu resolvo de uma maneira.
Coloco uma tag *data-url-base* ou *data-base*, como preferir, no *body*. Veja abaixo:

Caminho base do seu site. Tipo http://localhost/seusistema/public/
`<body data-url-base="{{ URL::to('') }}">`

Daí no seu JS faça assim:

```js
// Variável Global - Tem que vir primeiro de tudo.
var urlBase; 

// Dentro do document.ready

$(document).ready(function(){
urlBase = $('body').data('url-base');  
)}
```

Depois no seu Ajax na linha:
`url: '/reserva/imprimir',`

Coloque a variável *urlBase*

`url: urlBase + '/reserva/imprimir',`

E além disso sua função deve ter o mesmo nome do link na URL do Ajax. Você está chamando via POST a URL /reserva/imprimir. Portanto, sua função que vai fazer o download do PDF deve ser :

`public function postImprimir()`

É assim que está fazendo ?